# VS code change background color hover element in menu

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I change the blue color of the hovered element in menu?
Now I see that:

[image]

I want to change the blue with another color.
Thanks

Comment: Would like to know the same.

Answer (score 3):

In version 1.38, in settings.json create a "workbench.colorCustomizations" property if you don't already have it, then under that you can use the property "menu.selectionBackground".  Unfortunately, some settings like this have the word "hover" in the name, some use "focus" in the name, and in this case it is "selection", so it's not consistent.

Example:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "menu.selectionBackground": "#f0de77"
}
```

Be aware that this highlight/selection color is also controlled by the property "list.activeSelectionBackground", but "menu.selectionBackground" has preference.

Settings.json on Windows is usually located in this folder: %AppData%\Code\User, I don't know about other operating systems.

Comment: i don't disagree with you that the naming is confusing but will just point out that some "menus" have pre-selected items (like the command palatte) and you can hover over other items and some "menus" - like the OP's do not have a concept of a  pre-selected item at all.   So there are differences, that being said I still would've named this one `hover` and not `selection`.

Answer (score 0):

if you also want to change the background color of the menu.

Find "Preferences: Open Configuration (JSON)" and run it. This should open settings.json in a new window.

```
"menu.background": "#282626"
```